# How do network users compensate for a late 802.11 beacon?

Tags: networking, delay, standards, beacon, wifi

From Wikipedia:

> Stations must schedule beacon transmission at the nominal beacon
>   interval. However, the transmission may suffer some delays due to the
>   channel access. Like other frames, beacons must follow the CSMA/CA
>   algorithm. This means that if the channel is busy (e.g., another
>   station is currently sending a frame) when the beacon needs to be
>   sent, it must wait. This means that the actual beacon interval may
>   differ from the nominal beacon interval [3]. **However, stations are
>   able to compensate for this difference by inspecting the timestamp in
>   the beacon frame when it is finally sent**."

My question is: does "compensate" mean that all further beacon arrivals will be delayed by the offset that caused the first delay? Is this part of the 802.11 standard?

Assume I expect beacons at T, 2T, 3T etc. If I actually receive the first beacon at (T+1), then should I expect beacons at (T+1), 2(T+1), 3(T+1) etc. OR (T+1), 2T, 3T etc.? Both of these are compensations but I'm looking to understand what the 802.11 standard says.

Answer (score 0):

`Compensate` here means even if there is a drift in the WIFI Station's (STA) local TSF timer (own local timer) or if the STA misses one beacon due to Access Point's (AP) channel access issues causing beacon delay, whenever the wifi STA is able to receive the next beacon, it will set its timer to be in sync with AP's timer (TSF) by copying the timestamp value in the received beacon and adding some "error correction" to it. This helps ensure a WIFI STA is always in sync with AP's TBTT so that it can wake up (in case of power save) or generally enable itself to predict the next beacon's reception time.

Answer to your questions:

> My question is: does "compensate" mean that all further beacon
>   arrivals will be delayed by the offset that caused the first delay? Is
>   this part of the 802.11 standard?

No, `compensate` does not mean that. As I explained above, it means that the STA will use the beacon timestamp and some "error correction" value to compensate for MAC/PHY delays to synchronize its TSF timer with that of APs.

> Assume I expect beacons at T, 2T, 3T etc. If I actually receive the
>   first beacon at (T+1), then should I expect beacons at (T+1), 2(T+1),
>   3(T+1) etc. OR (T+1), 2T, 3T etc.?

No, you should not expect beacons to come T+1, 2(T+1), etc. They will still follow the `Beacon Interval (BI)` difference between their arrival since AP will transmit its next beacon according to its TSF timer exactly BI interval apart from last one (discounting the fact that the earlier one got delayed due to channel access delays). The beacon's don't drift in time due to channel access delays.

The relevant part of the 802.11 spec which has more exact details is as follows:

> 11.1 Synchronization All STAs within a single BSS shall be synchronized to a common clock using the mechanisms defined herein.
>   11.1.1 Basic approach A Timing Synchronization Function (TSF) keeps the timers for all STAs in the same BSS synchronized. All STAs shall
>   maintain a local TSF timer.
>
> 11.1.1.1 TSF for infrastructure networks In an infrastructure BSS, the AP shall be the timing master for the TSF. The AP shall initialize its
>   TSF timer independently of any simultaneously started APs in an effort
>   to minimize the synchronization of the TSF timers of multiple APs. The
>   AP shall periodically transmit special frames called Beacon frames
>   that contain a copy of its TSF timer to synchronize the TSF timers of
>   other STAs in a BSS. A receiving STA shall always accept the timing
>   information in Beacon frames sent from the AP servicing its BSS. If a
>   STA’s TSF timer is different from the timestamp in the received Beacon
>   frame, the receiving STA shall set its local TSF timer to the received
>   timestamp value. Beacon frames shall be generated for transmission by
>   the AP once every dot11BeaconPeriod TUs.
>
> 11.1.2 Maintaining synchronization Each STA shall maintain a TSF timer with modulus 264 counting in increments of microseconds. STAs expect
>   to receive Beacon frames at a nominal rate. The interval between
>   Beacon frames is defined by the dot11BeaconPeriod parameter of the
>   STA. A STA sending a Beacon frame shall set the value of the Beacon
>   frame’s timestamp so that it equals the value of the STA’s TSF timer
>   at the time that the data symbol containing the first bit of the
>   timestamp is transmitted to the PHY plus the transmitting STA’s delays
>   through its local PHY from the MAC-PHY interface to its interface with
>   the WM [e.g., antenna, light- emitting diode (LED) emission surface].
>
> 11.1.2.4 TSF timer accuracy Upon receiving a Beacon frame with a valid FCS and BSSID or SSID, as described in 11.1.2.3, a STA shall update
>   its TSF timer according to the following algorithm: The received
>   timestamp value shall be adjusted by adding an amount equal to the
>   receiving STA’s delay through its local PHY components plus the time
>   since the first bit of the timestamp was received at the MAC/PHY
>   interface. In the case of an infrastructure BSS, the STA’s TSF timer
>   shall then be set to the adjusted value of the timestamp. In the case
>   of an IBSS, the STA’s TSF timer shall be set to the adjusted value of
>   the received timestamp, if the adjusted value of the timestamp is
>   later than the value of the STA’s TSF timer. The accuracy of the TSF
>   timer shall be no worse than ±0.01%.

Another slightly simpler explanation you can find in the link below; however it is not complete. For completeness, you should refer `section 11. MLME` of 802.11 spec.
https://flylib.com/books/en/2.519.1/timer_synchronization.html